# How to set a push button in matlab GUIDE that will direct the user to command window?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am planning to add a push button to my GUI which will direct user to the command window after clicking it. May I know what is the code or command to perform this function?

Thank you in advance and appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `commandwindow` with the button. It will do what you need.[Command window in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/commandwindow.html)